# Proving after n seconds all of intersection points of an infinite by infinite grid become the same color

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Consider an infinite by infinite grid.
We color the intersection points of the gird in the following method:

1. $n$ points are colored black
2. the remaining points are colored white

Now every second the colors change in this way:
every point changes its color to the color of the point among these there points:itself,the point above it,the point to the right; which its color is repeated at least two times!
in better words:each time the color of a point is changed base on which color is repeated more among itself and two other neighbors (right hand-side and above).the color that is repeated more(two to three times) is the color that this point changes to.

Prove that after $n$ seconds all of the points are going to be white.

for the solution I only could get so far:
if in the $k$th second a point is black then at least $k$ black points should existed above and right of that point.
I don't know it is useful or not are how can it be used exactly

Comment: Translation.  A point remains the same if the color of the point above and the color of the point to the right are different and if those colors are the same, then the point changes to that color.

Comment: Nope. A white point does not become black when its upper and right neighbor are white. The new color of each point is a simple "majority from 3" decision, taking the point itself and its upper and right neighbor into account.